# Keras Image and Mask Augmentation for CNN

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use ImageDataGenerator and .flow() from Keras in order to augment image data in real-time for a CNN segmentation task. Apologies in advance for my basic understanding of this type of programming, as I am quite new to it. I have a function below, which is aimed at augmenting the image data and corresponding data mask:

```py
def image_augmentation(imgs, masks): 
    #  create two instances with the same arguments
    # create dictionary with the input augmentation values
    data_gen_args = dict(featurewise_center=False,
                         featurewise_std_normalization=False,
                         rotation_range=90.,
                         width_shift_range=0.1,
                         height_shift_range=0.1,
                         zoom_range=0.2, 
                         horizontal_flip=True,
                         vertical_flip = True)
    ## use this method with both images and masks
    image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
    mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

    # Provide the same seed and keyword arguments to the fit and flow methods
    seed = 1
    ## fit the augmentation model to the images and masks with the same seed
    image_datagen.fit(imgs, augment=True, seed=seed)
    mask_datagen.fit(masks, augment=True, seed=seed)
    ## set the parameters for the data to come from (images)
    image_generator = image_datagen.flow(
        imgs,
        batch_size=32,
        shuffle=True,
        seed=seed)
    ## set the parameters for the data to come from (masks)
    mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow(
        masks,
        batch_size=32,
        shuffle=True,
        seed=seed)

    # combine generators into one which yields image and masks
    train_generator = zip(image_generator, mask_generator)
    ## return the train generator for input in the CNN 
    return train_generator
```

From my understanding, train generator should be composed of 32 augmented images and corresponding masks. However, when I run:

```py
train_generator = image_augmentation(imgs_train, imgs_spine_mask_train)
        ## run the fit generator CNN
model.fit_generator(train_generator,steps_per_epoch=100,epochs=5000, callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
```

image_augmentation just runs forever..no errors

imgs_train, imgs_spine_mask_train are both 4d arrays

Could anyone clue me into what I am doing wrong here? Of note, I completely new to stackoverflow so if I can change formatting etc. please let me know.

Cheers,

Comment: After reading up on generators, I believe the problem is that you cannot return an infinite generator(?). Therefore I have added:

while True:
        yield(image_generator.next(), mask_generator.next())

instead of return in the image_augmentation function. 

This appears to be working as:

train_generator = image_augmentation(imgs_train, imgs_spine_mask_train)
    ## run the fit generator CNN
    model.fit_generator(train_generator,steps_per_epoch=100,epochs=5000,  callbacks=[model_checkpoint])

Both run.

Comment: with the edit of @mccoyd the code is working for me